# Ну(,) разве я плохой?

Tags: запятые

Нужна ли запятая в «Ну(,) разве я плохой?»?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. ***Ну разве я плохой?** Не такой уж я плохой! Вот я щеночка погладил рукой.*

НУ — усилительная частица, нет паузы. Риторический вопрос:  неужели  меня можно считать плохим? Такой вопрос предполагает несогласие в ответе.

2. *Вот я щеночка погладил рукой. **Ну,  разве я плохой?***

НУ — междометие, выделяется паузой.  Используется для побуждения к действию. Обычный вопрос (ну, скажите, можно ли считать меня плохим).